# Getting "(undefined local variable or method" error when tryihng to create a form to update multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, config

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I want to have a form that will update a group of objects, using checkboxes to mark each of the IDs I want to update.  I was tryihn to follow this Railscast — http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes.  I have this in my controller serving the page and processing the submissions

```
def list
  @page_id = "list"
  @my_objects = MyObject.where(enabled: true)
  render :partial => 'list'
end

def enabled
  MyObject.update_all(["enabled=?", true], :id => params[:ids])
end
```

In my view, I have this

```
<%= form_tag enabled_my_objects_path, :method => :put do %>
```

But I don’t know what to put in my config/routes.rb file.  I tried this

```
resources :my_objects, :collection => { :enabled => :put }
```

but I get this error when my page is served

```
Error (undefined local variable or method `enabled_my_objects_path'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is off for declaring a collection route. Add a block to `resources` and declare your collection there:

```
resources :my_objects do
  put :enabled, on: :collection
end
```